# Multiple game sessions

Tags: java, netty

I started using Netty and yet haven't figured how to set up my protocol.

What I am trying to achieve is handling multiple game sessions on one server.

The `ChannelGroup` class is really helpful for my scenario, but I am wondering how for example I could set a list of game sessions without the server throwing `ConcurrentModificationException` when multiple operations are issued on the list simultaneously.

```
public class GameSession {
    int id;
    ChannelGroup channels;
}

public class MyServerHandler extends ChannelHandlerAdapter{
    private List<GameSession> sessions;

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        if(msg.equals(CREATE_ROOM))
        {
            sessions.add(new GameSession());
        }
        else if(msg.equals(JOIN_ROOM))
        {
            // look for specific room...
            // loop here can collide with the above block and throw ConcurrentModificationException  
        }
    }
}
```

Am I thinking about it the right way? How can I implement such behavior?

Comment: ChannelGroup is thread-safe, but List objects are not.  Try using Collections.synchronizedList().  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29

Comment: for each game session you will have several channels??

Comment: @Hector yes. Each session will have its own ChannelGroup

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the GameSession objects in a Map, from the Channel to the GameSession.

```
public class MyServerHandler extends ChannelHandlerAdapter{
    private Map<Channel, GameSession> sessions;

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        if(msg.equals(CREATE_ROOM))
        {
            sessions.put(ctx.channel(), new GameSession());
        }
        else if(msg.equals(JOIN_ROOM))
        {
            GameSession session = sessions.get(ctx.channel());
            // Could check if the key exists, or if the session is null, etc.
        }
    }
}
```